# iPhone4: Keep playing songs after song selected from Search iPhone screen ends?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, ipod.app

When I first got my iPhone 4, if I selected a song from the "search iPhone" screen (when you hit home twice), iTunes would start playing a playlist of all my songs, starting with the selected one.

I recently updated it to 4.2.1 (I don't remember exactly what I was at before). Now, when I select a song from the "Search iPhone" screen, iTunes starts playing a playlist containing only that song.

Is there a way I can get the old behavior back?

Comment: The situation has improved slightly in 4.3 (8F190): now when I select a song from spotlight search, it creates a playlist with all the songs on that album. I tried @byachna's recommendation again, but it did the same thing regardless of what mode I last used iTunes in (ie: album, songs, genre, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with the way you last accessed your iPod. If you open your iPod and  select songs and then select a song to play, the next time you search for a song, it will continue to play through all of your songs. If the last time you accessed the iPod by going to a particular album or playlist, it will only play the songs located in the same album or playlist as the song you searched for.

Its a little confusing but I could try to explain it better if you need me to.

Comment: I'd noticed that before too, when I first got the phone. This is different -- it is playing *exactly one* song, regardless of whether the iPod app was in song, artist, or album mode last time.